# Does BufferedImage.createGraphics() called many times create unnecessary overhead?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm doing some graphics programming in Java using the BufferedImage. I have some code that looks a bit like this (generic example)

```java
public void drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    Graphics2D g = this.bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

I am concerned however that the `bufferedImage.createGraphics` is going to have a large amount of overhead. Is that correct, and if so what are the best practices involving caching the `Graphics2D`?

I need to be able to:

- make changes to the `BufferedImage`
- call one `update` function to draw the `BufferedImage` to the screen
- The `drawLine` and similar functions need to exist and I cannot just do all of the drawing in one function

Comment: I had a hard time choosing a title, let me know if it can be improved

Comment: Run a profiler on your code, if you want to know how much overhead the `createGraphics()` call causes.

Comment: @Andreas do you know of any good java profilers? The only ones I've come across have been paid-for and I don't want to spend money on one simple problem

Comment: You need to hone your research skill, because there are free profilers, including one that comes with Java. The major IDEs also have free profilers.

Comment: *Does it create overhead?* Yes. *Is it unnecessary?* Hard to say for sure, given the limited amount of information we have, but it sounds like for your use case, `createGraphics()` once, do a lot of draw/paint operations and then done is better. *Does it matter?* Impossible to know. If this is an interactive paint program, definitively no. If you are outputting real time graphs or so, probably yes.